# Extra fields in UserAdmin for AbstractUser

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I am not able to add custom fields defined in MyCustomUser to Add User form in admin. I can only add user with 2 basic fields - username and password. How can I extend the form with `extra_field`?

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyCustomUser(AbstractUser):
    extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

admin.site.register(MyCustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

I have already tried other stack overflow suggestions but they are overdated or simply does not work for me.

Comment: `How can I extend the form with` - Which form? Are you asking how can you add `extra_field` in your user signup/login form?

Answer (score -1):

Write `CustomUserAdmin` class and add your fields and register this in `admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin


class MyCustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['extra_field']
    ...

admin.site.register(MyCustomUser, MyCustomUserAdmin)
```